# Python in Grails

Tags: python, grails

I have come up to a brick wall.

I want to have a Python engine in my Grails application so that I can pass it some params and a script and get a result.

I have been looking around and only found one thing, which doesn't seem right by using Jython.

Has anyone done this or had any experience with doing a similar thing who can point me in the right direction.

Comment: may i ask why you would like to do this directly? i mean as grails runs on the java virtual machine, if you want to execute code in the same process as the grails process, you have to use the jvm - and then  Jython seems like a reasonable solution (altough i'm not sure if groovy & p(j)ython interoperate together well like groovy & java do). Another more suitable solution for me seems to do some kind of inter process communication, which is something like a http endpoint for your python code nowadays...

Comment: You should consider using a flask rest API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about create a rest service for your python script?

Like http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask